# Can't delete records from database with Axios React Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, reactjs, axios

I'm having trouble deleting records from the database using Axios in React (front end). I use Django REST 2.2 for my backend.

The URL "http://localhost:8000/api/manager/courses/" works, I can add, update & delete courses. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Delete function Axios front end React (The url routs to the viewset seen below)

```
  const handleDelete = (item) => {
    if (item.id) {
      axios
        .delete(`http://localhost:8000/api/manager/courses/${item.id}/`, item, {
          headers: {
            authorization: "Token " + getUserToken(),
          },
        })
        .then((response) => refreshList());
      handleCloseEdit();
      return;
    }
  };
```

ViewSet Django backend

```
class CourseView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Course.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CourseSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        if (self.request.user):
            return Course.objects.filter(manager_id=self.request.user.pk)
        else:
            return Course.objects.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        if (self.request.user.pk):
            serializer.save(manager_id = self.request.user)
        else:
            serializer.save()
```

EDIT: It works if I remove get_queryset. How come it interferes with Delete?

Comment: since its giving 404 error, the item you are trying to delete might not exist in the database in the firstplace

Comment: @vvk24 It does exist when debugging, also it does seem to work when I remove get_queryset. Any idea?

Comment: what is manager_id of object you are trying to delete

Comment: @iklinac It's a foreign key of the User model. I filter the courses by the manager_id which is the currently logged in user.

Comment: to expand my question as you didn't get me what is the manager_id value of object with id of 1 is it same as your logged in user?

Comment: @iklinac It's 1. But I'm not sure why that matters?

Comment: is it same as logged in user?

Comment: @iklinac Yep. I add and delete the course with the same user. Except I can't delete it.